# Stopped service shows up with [+] status

Tags: services

I'm trying to troubleshoot a system that keeps hanging intermittently, and I'm not a *nix expert by any means. I suspect a camera driver (supposedly there is a bug, waiting for more info from the manufacturer). I followed the instructions in their readme file to stop the daemon: `/etc/init.d/ueyeusbdrc stop` and I get the message 'Stopped ueyeusbd.'

When I run `service --status-all`, I get this service listed with [ + ], which is supposed to mean it's still running. But another attempt to stop it results in this error message: "No pidfile found. Cannot stop ueyeusbd". I seem to be able to start and stop the daemon, but it always shows up with a [ + ] in the `service` output.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

I really think this error message is specific to the ueyeusb daemon (ueyeusbd). If you check how they start it, they use:

```
/usr/bin/ueyeusbd -c /etc/ids/ueye/ueyeusbd.conf -P /var/run/ueyed/ueyeusbd.pid
```

As far as I understand, the error messages means that the file "ueyeusbd.pid" is missing.